# MySQL скрывать выполненное задание

Tags: php, mysql

Есть проект, где пользователи выкладывают задания, а другие его выполняют.
Суть вопроса: Нужно скрывать выполненные задания, НО не могу понять как это сделать, помогите решить задачу

Структура БД:
1 - таблица USERS
Данные: email, username, userpassword, ID, score

2 - таблица POSTS
Данные: ID, postname, author

Условия Заданий: Могут выполнить множество пользователей

Comment: Структуру своей базы покажите: задания, пользователи, оценки пользователей по заданиям.

Comment: Есть 2 таблицы.
POSTS, там хранятся данные: 
ID - auto_increment
postname

И 
таблица users, там всего-лишь хранятся: login, pass, email, score

Comment: @Memory16 , в тексте вопроса приложите схемы `posts`  и `users`

Comment: @МихаилРебров готово

Comment: А те самые задания, которые надо скрывать, в какой таблице находятся ? И где лежат результаты выполнения этих заданий ? Собственно вы можете не показывать задания, если для них есть записи в таблице выполнения или при отсутствии такой таблицы у вас на задании должен быть признак "выполнено", по которому собственно их так же можно скрывать

Comment: Аттрибут булевый добавить в таблицу заданий, если выполнен true - скрыть. Правильно я понял тебя?

Comment: @eldario
Я дополнил вопрос.
"Условия Заданий: Могут выполнить множество пользователей"
И если пользователь выполнил задание именно у него должно скрыться выполненное задание

Comment: Тогда создаем третью таблицу связей, где будут поля id increment, user_id, task. По выполнению заданий записываем имя пользователя и айди задания. Сделаешь JOIN и готово.

Comment: Должна существовать таблица выполнения, хранящая пары (ИД юзера - ИД задания).

Comment: @Memory16 Отлично, тогда у вас должна быть таблица выполнения заданий пользователями. буквально состоящая из двух полей id-задания, id-пользователя (ну возможно еще какие то поля, которые захотите) и тогда отображение заданий буквально будет `select * from posts p where not exists(select 1 from user_posts up where up.post_id=p.id and up.user_id=нужный-пользователь)` или то же самое с помощью left join

Comment: @Mike спасибо огромное, я думал о создании ещё одной таблицы, но думал. вдруг накосячу и всё испорчу)
Ещё раз спасибо)